# Akeneo CSV import remains on status: "starting"

Tags: php, database, file, import, akeneo

when I attempted to upload a CSV file to Akeneo (2.0) the status **remained on "starting"** and the job was never completed. I didn't receive an error message.  Also, I tried to define a path so that Akeneo could find the file. Unfortunately, in both cases the import didn't work.
In order to conduct the import properly, I considered to use the correct attributes in the csv file.

Which detail have I overlooked on the import?

Answer (score 3):

Did you by any chance forget to launch the job queue consumer daemon? You can do so by running the following command: `bin/console --env=prod akeneo:batch:job-queue-consumer-daemon` (see related doc here: https://docs.akeneo.com/2.3/install_pim/manual/daemon_queue.html)